# Unlock Account with Web3js Version 1.0?

Tags: web3js, accounts

In geth I can unlock my account via:

`personal.unlockAccount(address, password, seconds)`

in the **web3js v1.0** I cannot find a similar function in the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html).

How can I unlock my account with webjs v1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's just `web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount`. If you search the page you linked to for `unlockAccount`, you'll see it mentioned as a TODO. (Keep in mind that 1.0 is still in beta.)

**EDIT**

Per comments below, the issue was that `--rpcapi personal` was missing from the `geth`'s command line.

Comment: I already tried that like so: `web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(coinbase, 'test', 10)`, but I catch an error: `Error: Returned error: The method personal_unlockAccount does not exist/is not available` => the function does not exist?

Comment: What node are you connected to? I believe that error is coming from the node.

Comment: I am working on my private chain hosed by `geth v1.8.2-unstable-423c8bb1`. Could you give me some detail on how to test if my private chain is the problem?

Comment: Can you share your command-line parameters? Is `personal` included in your `--rpcapi` parameter?

Comment: `geth --datadir ./PrivateNet/chain --networkid 9987 --rpc --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8080"` command to start the blockchain. And yes the problem was the missing `--rpcapi eth,web3,personal`. The documentation is given here [Management APIS](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs). Thanks a lot! Post an answer and I'll close this question.

Comment: I edited this answer.